# How to show monthes/week day labels in english?

Tags: internationalization

How can I in kubuntu 20 to show monthes/week day labels in english, not in national ? I mean : 1) ex. console(command ls -la) 2) Date and Time wizard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you want to show date?

Comment: In what context? In the terminal? In the GUI? Where in the GUI? Where in the terminal? Please [edit] your question and explain what you need in more detail.

Comment: One way to do that is to set the `LC_TIME` environment variable to `en_DK.UTF-8`.

Comment: I tried to run in the console command : set LC_TIME = en_DK.UTF-8  But it did not help in my case...